# RegEx /href=.+"/g matching " repeatedly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string using this RegEx: /href=.+"/g

```
var str= '<a href="https://www.url.com" target="_blank">';
console.log(str.match(/href=.+"/g));
```

however, I only want it to match this much: `href="https://www.url.com"`

Instead, it's matching this much: `href="https://www.url.com" target="_blank"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.+
```

Matches 1 or more, for as many as possible, if you are trying to match until the nearest " ,then you will want as few as possible instead, so you will want

```
/href=.+?"/g
```